# How to add a controller to my own robot?

Tags: ros, geometry-msgs, base-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am building a simple robot from scratch because I want to learn the complete procedure of building a robot.

I already built a robot like this(in urdf file):
[image: image description]

And I want to send the command(geometry_msgs/Twist) to move the robot, I don't know how to correctly send the command to the robot.

There are some resources, but I am not familiar with controllers, so I have difficulties reading these resources. Hope these provide some useful hints.
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo

http://answers.ros.org/question/55082/error-adding-controller-script-in-simple-urdf-model-to-be-simulated-on-gazebo/

http://answers.ros.org/question/12050/simple-urdf-controller-example/

Is there simple answers that I can control the robot?

Thanks in advance, I know this might be a simple question for you guys :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100241/how-to-add-a-controller-to-my-own-robot?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way to do this is to implement a custom Gazebo plugin. We've done that in the package [diffdrive_gazebo_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/diffdrive_gazebo_plugin). To use it, you'll have to add it to your URDF, like [here](https://github.com/uos/kurt_driver/blob/hydro/kurt_base/urdf/kurt_indoor.urdf.xacro#L60). If you want to see it in action, you can use the [kurt_empty_world.launch](https://github.com/uos/kurt_driver/blob/hydro/kurt_gazebo/launch/kurt_empty_world.launch) file to start it, and [uos_diffdrive_teleop](https://github.com/uos/uos_tools/blob/hydro/uos_diffdrive_teleop/launch/key.launch) to send Twist commands.

Our plugin is for a six-wheeled robot, but modifying it for your four-wheeled robot shouldn't be too hard.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-11-21**:
Thanks~ this answer is really helpful: )